# How to convert rows to columns in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, transpose

For a requirement I have to create a query to show Employees Schedule per week. Query is like this:

```
select weekday, sched_hrs
  from table
 where emplid = '12345'
   and weekday_name= 1
```

Output of this query is like:

```
Weekday |  Sched_hrs
-------------------- 
   1    |    7.6
   1    |    7.6
   1    |    7.6
   1    |    7.6
   1    |    7.6
   1    |    OFF
   1    |    OFF
```

I want the output in below format:

```
1   7.6  7.6   7.6   7.6   7.6   OFF  OFF
```

How to achieve it?

Comment: try using `listagg` functions

Comment: If you are OK with concatenated list, then use LISTAGG, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with **concatenated list**, then use **LISTAGG** which was introduced in `Oracle 11g Release 2`.

```
SELECT weekday, LISTAGG(Sched_hrs, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY weekday) AS Sched_hrs
FROM   table 
 WHERE emplid = '12345' AND weekday_name= 1
GROUP BY weekday;
```

For example,

```
SQL> column employees format a50
SQL> SELECT deptno, LISTAGG(ename, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ename) AS employees
  2  FROM   emp
  3  GROUP BY deptno;

    DEPTNO EMPLOYEES
---------- --------------------------------------------------
        10 CLARK,KING,MILLER
        20 ADAMS,FORD,JONES,SCOTT,SMITH
        30 ALLEN,BLAKE,JAMES,MARTIN,TURNER,WARD

SQL>
```

Answer (score -1):

In 11g you can use the PIVOT function.  See the documentation:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html