# Oracle: Convert rows into columns for output of joined table queries

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, multiple-columns, rows

```
SELECT ABC.ID, ABC.URL1, ABC.URL2,
DECODE(ABC.TEXT,'URL3' ,ABC.URL),
DECODE(ABC.TEXT,'URL4',ABC.URL),
DECODE(ABC.TEXT,'URL5',ABC.URL),
DECODE(ABC.TEXT,'URL6',ABC.URL),
DECODE(ABC.TEXT,'URL7',ABC.URL),
DECODE(ABC.TEXT,'URL8',ABC.URL),
DECODE(ABC.TEXT,'URL9',ABC.URL)
FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT t1.ID, t2.URL1, t2.URL2,
t4.TEXT AS TEXT, t3.URL AS URL
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.id2 
LEFT JOIN table4 t3 ON t3.id=t2.id2
LEFT JOIN table4 t4 ON t3.id3=t4.id
WHERE t1.id='VALUE'))ABC;
```

I want the output as below:
[image]

and values for those urls in respective columnst1

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557467/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-in-oracle-sql

Comment: I tried but it's not helping when I have multiple tables joined.

Comment: @Abhinav Show what you tried. If joining multiple tables is causing the issue, you can generally get around it by selecting from the join by surrounding it with parenthesis, something like `select * from (select ... from a join b join c ...)`

Comment: @BrianLeach You can see in the code which I have pasted in original question that I have surrounded sql with parenthesis. But then too it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code worked for me:

```
SELECT DEF.ID, DEF.URL1, DEF.URL2,
MAX(DECODE(ABC.TEXT,'URL3' ,ABC.URL)) URL3,
MAX(DECODE(ABC.TEXT,'URL4',ABC.URL)) URL4,
MAX(DECODE(ABC.TEXT,'URL5',ABC.URL)) URL5,
MAX(DECODE(ABC.TEXT,'URL6',ABC.URL)) URL6,
MAX(DECODE(ABC.TEXT,'URL7',ABC.URL)) URL7,
MAX(DECODE(ABC.TEXT,'URL8',ABC.URL)) URL8,
MAX(DECODE(ABC.TEXT,'URL9',ABC.URL)) URL9
FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT t1.ID, t2.URL1, t2.URL2,
t4.TEXT AS TEXT, t3.URL AS URL
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.id2 
LEFT JOIN table4 t3 ON t3.id=t2.id2
LEFT JOIN table4 t4 ON t3.id3=t4.id
WHERE t1.id='VALUE')ABC) DEF
GROUP BY DEF.ID, DEF.URL1, DEF.URL2;
```